# Bash string difference - print changes only

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm looking for a way to print out the different between two strings, and clear all characters except the difference between them.

for example:

```
String1: "$$$$"
String2: "^^$$$$**"
```

The expected result is: `"^^**"`

Comment: How is `$$$$` supposed to be equal to `####`?

Comment: Ok, so what did you try?

Comment: @devius See again:)

Comment: How did you assign "^^$$$$$**" to a variable in bash? Do we have to consider diff (a, b) to be the same as diff (b, a)? Is b always longer? What is the diff of ("1122", "11-22-1122")? "11-22-" or "--1122", each or undefined?

Comment: Without more sample inputs and outputs it’s hard to say what the logic is supposed to be. What if, for instance, the two strings are `foo` and `bar`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use double quotes, "$$" will be expanded to current shell PID. So you should use backslash to keep the $ symbol: "\$\$\$\$" or use singular quotes.
The question is still not clear, but there is a chance that you need something like this:

```
string1='$$$$'
string2='^^$$$$**'
if [ ${#string1} -ge ${#string2} ]
then
    echo ${string1/$string2}
else
    echo ${string2/$string1}
fi
```